# d-link print servers and logging

Tags: logging, print-server, d-link

I have a d-link print server in my network. (dpr-2000)

It has a print log which displays which computers in the network have sent print jobs.
But it only saves the last 20 history.

Is there any way so that i can grab this info from the print server and saving them some where?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Not to question your motives, but what possible purpose could you have for keeping the logs of end user print jobs? Do you bill the users for printing? If so, then you should implement a proper auditing solution. If not, then it's just mindless, unproductive user monitoring that serves no purpose. Do you need to know how many times they've clicked the right mouse button as well?

Answer (score 0):

Well you'd do this with SNMP. But this device does not support SNMP (from what I've read). So the only thing you really can do is setup a printer server (CUPS) or something and forward the jobs to the dpr-2000. Then you can log that way.

Comment: yah, it has SNMP. How can i use it for this purpose?

Comment: Oh, my bad. On the documentation it said "Not available". It is easier to find a MIB tree for the device, so you know what to probe. You can snmp-walk the device and see what values are there for you to use. Once you find the values you want to use, you can use many applications to probe the device. If you are going down this route start with [www.net-snmp.org](http://www.net-snmp.org/). This is the generic protocol to get information out of network devices. It can be quite time consuming.